# Flexisip Linphone don't revice incoming call when in background mode

Tags: linphone, sip-server

I using Linphone to build VOIP app on iOS, backend SIP server using Flexisip.

If 2 users are in my application, incoming call will well working.

But if 1 user exit app (press home buttom), incoming call will unstable working ( sometimes well working, sometimes not )

How do i fix ?

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you using official Linphone from iTunes Connect or did you built it/customized it?

Comment: No. I using Linphone lib to build my voip app, don't use offficial Linphone app from Store. ( but i test official Linphone app, it also don't receive incoming call when in background mode )

Comment: You should first try that it works with official application and linphone.org account. If it works, then test official app and your server. If that works then the issue is with your custom app. Otherwise it's an issue with your server. For instance you must use TCP or TLS transport, not UDP, to receive background calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you build the app on your own:

1. You need to apply for a VoIP push certification from https://developer.apple.com and deploy it to Flexisip.
2. Make sure you modify the register message like the code LinphoneManager.m did, attach "pn-type", "app-id", "pn-tok" and so on to Contact Header.